Go JSON differentiating zero values vs null vs undefined
I know Go JSON issues are a-dime-a-dozen; the existing stdlib JSON package is clunky. There is ongoing discussion about a v2. Until then, I'm hoping someone can lend some inspiration here on how to create a robust solution for nullable, optional/undefined-able, and zero values.
Null, undefined, and zero values usually have different semantics (e.g. JSON Merge Patch), so it's important to differentiate between them, but Go lumps them all into Go zero values. Using pointers, we can differentiate between null/undefined and a value, but we can't differentiate between null AND undefined AND a value.
Here are my attempts to differentiate zero vs null vs undefined:
Attempt 1: playground - fails marshalling undefined, intuitive syntax
type Optional[T any] struct {
    Value *T
}
func (o *Optional[T]) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) { return json.Marshal(o.Value)}
func (o *Optional[T]) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error { o.Value = new(T); return json.Unmarshal(data, o.Value) }

type X struct {
    Y Optional[*int] `json:"y,omitempty"` // Trying to make this optional AND nullable
}

This almost works:

✅ Unmarshal {} -> X.Y.Value is nil
✅ Unmarshal {"y": null} -> X.Y.Value is non-nil, *X.Y.Value is nil
✅ Unmarshal {"y": 0} -> X.Y.Value is non-nil, *X.Y.Value is non-nil, **X.Y.Value is 0
❌ Marshal X.Y.Value is nil -> does not marshal to {} but instead it marshals to {"y":null}

stdlib encoding/json's omitempty does not apply to zero-value structs


✅ Marshal X.Y.Value is non-nil, *X.Y.Value is nil -> {"y": null}
✅ Marshal X.Y.Value is non-nil, *X.Y.Value is non-nil, **X.Y.Value is 0 -> {"y": 0}

Attempt 2: playground - fails unmarshalling null, requires *Optional[T] in order to be truly optional
type Optional[T any] struct {
    Value T `json:",inline"`
}
func (o *Optional[T]) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)    { return json.Marshal(&o.Value) }
func (o *Optional[T]) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error { return json.Unmarshal(data, &o.Value) }

type X struct {
    Y *Optional[*int] `json:"y,omitempty"` // Trying to make this optional AND nullable
}


✅ Unmarshal {} -> X.Y is nil
❌ Unmarshal {"y": null} -> X.Y is nil

since X.Y is a pointer itself (*Optional[*int]), a null value sets X.Y to nil instead of calling Optional[*int].UnmarshalJSON.


✅ Unmarshal {"y": 0} -> X.Y is non-nil, *X.Y.Value is non-nil, *X.Y.Value is 0
✅ Marshal X.Y is nil -> {}
✅ Marshal X.Y is non-nil, X.Y.Value is nil -> {"y": null}
✅ Marshal X.Y is non-nil, X.Y.Value is non-nil, *X.Y.Value is 0 -> {"y": 0}

Attempt 3: playground - works, unsafe, fails go vet, not as pretty
type Optional[T any] uintptr
func (o *Optional[T]) SetValue(t T)                 { *o = Optional[T](unsafe.Pointer(&t)) }
func (o *Optional[T]) UnsetValue()                  { *o = 0 }
func (o *Optional[T]) Value() *T                    { return (*T)(unsafe.Pointer(*o)) }
func (o *Optional[T]) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) { return json.Marshal((*T)(unsafe.Pointer(*o))) }
func (o *Optional[T]) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    t := new(T)
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, t)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *o = Optional[T](unsafe.Pointer(t))
    return nil
}

type X struct {
    Y Optional[*int] `json:"y,omitempty"` // Trying to make this optional AND nullable
}


✅ Unmarshal {} -> X.Y.Value() is nil
✅ Unmarshal {"y": null} -> X.Y.Value() is non-nil, *X.Y.Value() is nil
✅ Unmarshal {"y": 0} -> X.Y.Value() is non-nil, *X.Y.Value() is non-nil, **X.Y.Value() is 0
✅ Marshal X.Y.UnsetValue() -> {}
✅ Marshal X.Y.SetValue(nil) -> {"y": null}
✅ Marshal X.Y.SetValue(<pointer to 0>) -> {"y": 0}

Closing
My preference would be Attempt 1 (if it worked, obviously). The syntax seems intuitive to me:

undefined: Optional[*Type].Value is nil
null: *Optional[*Type].Value is nil
value: **Optional[*Type].Value is the value

Anyone have a solution to differentiate zero/null/undefined for both marshalling and unmarshalling?

Why do you need to differentiate between null and undefined? What's the semantic distinction you're trying to encode there? I thought undefined wasn't legal in JSON anyway.

If you really need to differentiate between null and a nonexistent field, you can use json.RawMessage.

@MarkReed, undefined as in not-present not the JavaScript type undefined. JSON Merge Patch makes a distinction between null and undefined: null="remove this field", undefined="do nothing to this field".

"JSON Merge Patch" some things, while existing and specified, make little sense and are just too complicated irl.

@Volker, I find JSON Merge Patch quite intuitive, but it's also not the only example of where undefined and null have different semantics (OpenAPI specs treat null as a separate concept from required/optional properties).
But speaking of JSON Merge Patch, Go's JSON v2 discussion says they're "[taking] inspiration from JSON Merge Patch". https://github.com/golang/go/discussions/63397#discussioncomment-7201220

@BurakSerdar I haven't figured out a clean way to use json.RawMessage that doesn't require every struct with "Optional" fields to implement a custom Unmarshal/MarshalJSON method. I'd be happy to accept an answer from you, if you can show me what you're thinking.

Somewhat verbose, but if you declare Field json.RawMessage, then string(x.Field)=="null" tells you it is null, len(x.Field)==0  tells you it is missing. If both fails, json.Unmarshal(x.Field) gives you the value.

You can define a type that explicitly unmarshalls null to something other than the zero value. Rather than mess around with pointers, it's simpler (I think) to have an enumeration that distinguishes between the three cases; null, undefined and a value.
For example, this code:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type FieldType int

const (
    Undefined = FieldType(0)
    Value     = FieldType(1)
    Null      = FieldType(2)
)

type PatchField[T any] struct {
    Type FieldType
    V    T
}

var (
    nullToken = []byte("null")
)

func (pt *PatchField[T]) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    *pt = PatchField[T]{Type: Undefined}
    if bytes.Equal(b, nullToken) {
        pt.Type = Null
        return nil
    }
    pt.Type = Value
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &pt.V)
}

type X struct {
    Y PatchField[int] `json:y`
}

func (pt PatchField[T]) String() string {
    switch pt.Type {
    case Undefined:
        return "undefined"
    case Null:
        return "null"
    default:
        return fmt.Sprint(pt.V)
    }
}

func main() {
    cs := []string{`{"y": null}`, `{}`, `{"y": 42}`}
    for _, c := range cs {
        var x X
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(c), &x); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
        }
    }
}


This handles unmarshalling perfectly, so far as I can see. Marshalling will be a problem though when trying to omit undefined PatchFields. You'll have to add the omit logic in a func (x *X) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) (same for every other type in which you want to use PatchField).
